# "Internal Server Error 500" while using .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471056/internal-server-error)

I am looking to change the URL of my website in php, so i am using .htaccess file for this but it showing me **Internal Server Error 500**.

Can anyone please help me out how to solve the server error?

Looking for your valuable views.

Comment: Check your Apache error log.

Comment: Internal Server Error 500 is mostly due to syntax error in .htaccess, please show code.

Comment: can we saw the contents of htaccess file?

Comment: Any redirect in .htaccess ?

Answer (score 7):

Finding out what is causing the 500 Server Error
**Here are some basic steps that you can use to find out what is causing the error.**

- Open the Error Logs tool, located in the Logs section of the cPanel.
- Reload the web page that is causing the error. Reload the Error Logs page.
- Search the error logs for your IP Address for any errors
  associated with it, your IP address is located at the top of the
  page.

**There are 3 main reasons why you will see this error:**

1. File or Folder Permissions.
2. Bad code or syntaxes in your .htaccess.
3. Improperly configured php.ini.

**File or Folder Permissions**

[Sun Jun 05 12:03:22 2011] [error] [client 66.249.72.82] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home1/examplec/public_html" is writeable by group

In this scenario, your account has a folder with an invalid permission set. To correct this, simply restore the permissions to "755" from "777."
While each site can be different, the following permissions are most often the correct permissions to use:

Files - 644
CGI Scripts - 755
Directories - 755

You can modify permissions with the File Manager, located in the Files category of the cPanel, an FTP client, or using the "chmod" command in SSH/Bash.
For more information on how to change File and Folder permissions please see our Knowledge Base article Setting file and user permissions

**Bad code or syntaxes in your .htaccess**

There is a huge range of things .htaccess can do and isn't difficult to use, however if you do not enter the syntax correctly it can result in a Server 500 Error. Some common examples of what could cause an error are listed below.

**Syntax Not Closed**

[Sun Jun 05 12:11:38 2011] [alert] [client 66.249.72.82] /home1/examplec/public_html/.htaccess: /home1/examplec/public_html/.htaccess:3: ExampleRule/Module> was not closed.

Again, the solution is to simply fix the syntax, or remove it. In this case, close the ending "" directive properly and put the rules on their own line to resolve the problem.

These are just a few common examples that can be caused by bad .htaccess parameters. What you encounter will likely vary, however generally the error message is descriptive enough to determine an error from it without further investigation.
Improperly configured php.ini
ForceType

When you are using files with (or without) an extension different then the normal extension for that filetype you can use ForceType in your .htaccess file to make it clear to the server how to handle that file (or all the files in the folder) (this works on servers without phpsuexec).

An example: When you have a file called 'item' (like Nucleus uses for FancyURL's) and want it to be parsed by the server as php you use the following code in your .htaccess file:

```
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
```

However, because our servers use phpsuexec this will result in an internal server error. To solve this you can simply use SetHandler instead of ForceType, so your .htaccess-file becomes:

```
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
```

php_value
On a server without phpsuexec it is possible to use the php_value statement in a .htaccess file to change the settings of php (actually overwrite the settings from php.ini). On a sever with phpsuexec this will also result in a server error. To solve this you can use a php.ini file which you put in the same folder as where you would have put your .htaccess file. In that php.ini file you can change all the php values. You only have to put the values you want to modify in that file. By example if you want to set the short_open_tag to Off you would have used short_open_tag? = off in your .htaccess file. Using a php.ini file this results in:

```
[PHP]
short_open_tag = Off
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change ownership user of all files & folders.Then you must look permission of appropriate folders allowed properly.